# XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode returns null for root node

Tags: c#, xml, file-extension

I have several xml files whose postfix is not .xml, but .component
Now I want to handle them in the c# program, but It seems that the c# cant even find the root element of these xml files

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path); // MG: edited to Load based on comment
XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("rootNodename");
```

It seems that the root is null, How should I cope with this?

Comment: There could be multiple things going wrong here, I doubt it's the file extension.  Have you looked at "doc" in the debugger and verified that it's not loading?

Comment: can you post the first few lines of one of those XML files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you've resolved the `Load`/`LoadXml` confusion, I expect the issue is namespaces; do you have example xml? Handling xml with namespaces gets... "fun" ;-p

For example:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(@"<test xmlns='myFunkyUri' value='abc'/>");
    // wrong; no namespace consideration
    XmlElement root = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("test");
    Console.WriteLine(root == null ? "(no root)" : root.GetAttribute("value"));
    // right
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "myFunkyUri"); // x is my alias for myFunkyUri
    root = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("x:test", nsmgr);
    Console.WriteLine(root == null ? "(no root)" : root.GetAttribute("value"));
```

Note that even if your xml declares xml aliases, you may still need to re-declare them for your namespace-manager.

Comment: Yes, There actually some interesting problems with the default namespace(the one without prefix)

Answer (score 4):

LoadXml takes an XML string, not a file path.  Try Load instead.  Load doesn't care about the file extension.

Here is a link to the documention for Load:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx

Comment: Yes I made a mistake when I wrote the question
Actually I tried Load() too, LoadXml will generate a exception while Load() will load the file without problem but I just can not find the root node, the return is always null

Comment: Actually, I expect the real problem is namespaces... (see answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem try this: Putting a dash in front of rootNodename
Instead of this: 
XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("rootNodename");

Do this:
XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/rootNodename");